# Baby does not sleep on her own

Tags: infant, sleep-training

Our six month old daughter cant sleep on her own , a loud scream is an indicator that she wants to sleep , if all other things are ruled out.We need to take her to the swing and sing to make her sleep or at times if this does not work then we need to take her on the chest and roam around in the room.

Hence my question is how to train an infant([not a toddler](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4214/teaching-a-almost-3-year-old-she-can-fall-asleep-on-her-own)) to sleep on her own?

Comment: I believe the linked question covers this pretty well.  The other question is for a 3 month old, but the answers should apply to a six month old as well (or better, in some cases).